# What is the sum of irradiance magnitudes over all directions?

Tags: optics, radiation

I have a quantity that I’m thinking of, one that makes sense to me… but I can’t find a name for it, and I’m questioning whether I’m making a mistake and I’m not thinking of a clear idea after all. If it does make sense, then each of these three questions should have the same answer. I’d be grateful if someone could either judge whether these questions make sense or tell me the name of the quantity.

I’ll assume all quantities are over some frequency band. And I’m using the terms irradiance, radiant flux, radiant intensity, isotropic antenna, and effective aperture as their respective Wikipedia entries define them.

1. I’ve got one lamp to my north and another to my west. The irradiance
   I’m receiving from the north is two watts per square meter. The irradiance I’m receiving from the west is also two watts
   per square meter. What is it that I have four of at my location?
   Because irradiance is a vector, it’s not their sum; rather, it’s the
   sum of their magnitudes.
2. Say I have an ideal isotropic receiving antenna. What is the power
   received by my antenna, divided by its effective aperture?
3. Say I have a sphere of radius $r$. Say $P$ is total radiant flux, or
   power, incident over this sphere. What is $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{P}{4 \pi r^2}$?

What I’m looking for would clearly have dimension power per area, like irradiance, but it would be a scalar quantity.

What I’m not looking for is the integral of irradiance over the surface of a sphere; that would be total radiant flux in units of power. Nor am I looking for the integral of radiant intensity over all directions; that also would be radiant flux.

Comment: You have a **major** misunderstanding. Irradiance is **not** a vector, it is a scalar. It is true that the Wiki entry mentions the Poynting vector, but note that only its modulus is present. The "cos" menas that, for the same source of light, the irradiance on a surface placed at a slanting angle to the source, the irradiance is less than if the surface faces the source. For instance suppose a source north such that you would receive two watts per square meter on a vertical surface oriented east-west, and a source west such that you would receive **one** watts per square meter on a vertical su

Comment: Well, if it's not a vector, it's at least surface-oriented, right? I'd be curious to understand the mathematical distinction better (your comment got cut off), but for my immediate purposes, the implication seems the same: Irradiance only makes sense given a point and a direction (the normal of the surface), but scalar irradiance makes sense given a point alone.

Comment: I think I see the distinctions now: A vector field gives a vector as a function of location, a scalar field (such as scalar irradiance) gives a scalar as a function of location, and with a surface-oriented scalar (such as irradiance) we have a scalar as a function of both location and direction. I'd appreciate knowing if that's wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, this is right. In fact, the scalar irradiance is just the scalar product of the Poynting vector with the normal to the surface. But though it is true that the total of the scalar irradiance of some surface  for several sources is just **sum of the scalar products** of each Poynting vector with the normal to the surface which technically is also the **scalar product of  the sum of the vectors** with the normal to the surface. But it is **not at all** a natural thing to do, to add several Poynting vectors and only take the scalar product at the end.

Comment: Did you mean to say irradiance, and not scalar irradiance? I find the names confusing, since they are, I now understand, both scalars. But it sounds like you're still describing a surface-oriented quantity, since you're talking about scalar products with the normal to the surface.

Comment: I mean what everyone calls just irradiance. I just used the adjective "scalar" because you used it and to remind you it is a scalar quantity. I did not mean to increase your confusion, I am sorry !

Comment: Not at all; you've helped me a lot. This other, non-surface-oriented "scalar irradiance" seems like it might be more commonly used in life sciences than physics.

Comment: There is only one scalar in this context, namely irradiance. Since it **is** a scalar, I used the term "scalar irradiance" to help you but that was a mistake, it led you to believe theur were two different notions there.

Comment: After I asked my original question, I found several sources discussing a "scalar irradiance" distinct from ordinary irradiance. See section 1.3 of [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=DXCl0fw__noC), [this document](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6630/2012sp/notes/02radiom.pdf) from a Cornell professor, or [this device for sale](http://www.biospherical.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=100:scalar&catid=31&Itemid=46) that actually measures it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer; the word for this is "scalar irradiance."